# How to match ColumnDefinition for 2 seperate Grids in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

As stated in the title I want to match the ColumnDefinitions of 2 seperate Grids. Further, I want 1 of the Grids to get it's column width automatically (ColumnDefinition Width = "Auto") and then the other Grid should match that width.
My XAML code below:

```
<Grid x:Name="TableHeaders" BackgroundColor="#8e8e8e" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>

<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
  <ScrollView>
    <controls:SelectableItemsView ItemsSource="{Binding XXX}" SelectedItems="{Binding XXX, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="list">
      <controls:SelectableItemsView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid Style="{StaticResource BodyGridStyle}" x:Name="TableData">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </controls:SelectableItemsView.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:SelectableItemsView>
  </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

Now I want the column width of the Grid "TableData" to define the column width of the Grid "TableHeaders", is there any way to do this since SharedSizeGroup is not a thing in Xamarin sadly...

Ps: I know the nesting looks weird, but i have my reasons for this :)

Edit:
For now I've set the TableHeaders Column Width to what i know is roughly going to be that of TableData, but this obviously is not ideal.
Until I know another way this is the best i can do right now.